# Call Functions at Random then Call a Different Function in Python

Tags: python

I am using `random.choice()` to randomly call functions in a list. It works ok but sometimes one of the criteria in the called function is not met so it does not run. When this happens I would like to call another, different function from the list.

func_list is populated dynamically and there may be one or multiple functions in the list.

Here's the code:

```
func_list[func_one, func_two, func_three]
random.choice(func_list)()
```

So, for example, say `func_two` was called but criteria in the function was not met I would like to call either `func_one` or `func_three` chosen at random. If the criteria in that function is not met I would like to call the other one.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: How do you know if a criteria is not met?

Comment: You could just [shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/random.html?#random.shuffle) the list or produce a [permutation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) and then work your way through the result until the criteria are met?

Answer (score 3):

To avoid calling the same function twice, I suggest shuffling the list and trying the functions one by one, e.g.

```py
func_list = [func_one, func_two, func_three]
func_list_shuffled = func_list[:]  # shallow copy
random.shuffle(func_list_shuffled)

for func in func_list_shuffled:
    try:
        func()
    except:
        pass
    else:
        # no exception ocurred
        break
else:
    print("all functions errored")
```

Answer (score 1):

A naive approach would be to add `func_list` as an argument to all of your functions and call the `random.choice()` if default function criteria is not met inside your functions. This would create a recursive solution until one of the functions do get executed.

> Drawback: Might continue infinitely if none of the functions meet the criteria.

Comment: You could return the `func_list` and override the old `func_list` to avoid a infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

Just keep trying until it eventually works and remove the item from the list so it can't be called again:

```
func_list[func_one, func_two, func_three]

while true:
    i = random.choice(range(func_list))
    try:        
        return func_list[i]()
    except:
        func_list = func_list.remove(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try out random chosen functions till something works, but remove them from the list if they do not provide the desired result

```py
# let functions follow this pattern
def base_func():
   if criterium:
       return False
   else:
       # Do something
       return True

func_list[func_one, func_two, func_three]

result = False
while result is False:
   if func_list == []:
       break
   chosen_func = random.choice(func_list)
   func_list.remove(chosen_func)  # Remove used function
   result = chosen_func()
```